# If hard disk is as fast as RAM, can it replace RAM

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, hardware

If hard disk is as fast as RAM in a computer, then can it replace RAM itself? If not what are the reasons behind?

Comment: If disk is as fast as memory, it should be able to replace memory.  However, we still need to understand that the different parts of memory create a hierarchy: registers -> cache -> memory -> disk -> offline storage.  And typically, the differentiating factors are cost, storage capacity, and speed.

Comment: This is off topic as it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Put that in as a close vote so I can vote on it.

Answer (score 3):

Off-topic - and my close vote is in, but my comment kept growing so I added it below.

---

Of course - ignoring other issues like integration (eg. CPU being able to directly access the "HDD RAM") and assuming "as fast as" covers *all* the different factors including latency, throughout, and consistency and there are no issues with durability, etc. In which case the answer is self-evident: a better X is a better X.

However, this is not even close to being the case and both *distinct* types of hardware are designed with different goals in mind and use different technology to achieve it.

For starters, even the fastest SSDs are still more than an *order of magnitude slower* than RAM.

Even within this general rule, *many* different aspects of "speed" must be taken into account - just because the *throughput* of a SSD might be 1/10th of memory doesn't mean it supports continuous random-access anywhere close to that of standard main memory! Storage devices are also generally always accessed in blocks - eg. 4k - which further makes them unsuitable to "replace" RAM without extreme integration re-designs.

RAM changes *alot* and it must do so very quickly and consistently so the CPU can run efficiently (even having to use the RAM over the much quicker L-cache can slow down a CPU *a lot*) - there is no room for a "GC pause" or full cache. On the other hand, storage devices have the property of being non-volatile. RAM can be much faster in part because it *is* volatile and doesn't have this property/restriction.

Now, what a fast storage device *can* and *does* do is it makes [Memory Paging / Swap usage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) *significantly faster* than it has been historically - this *supplements* RAM (possibly allowing a system to achieve the same performance with *less* main memory), but is not used to "replace" RAM outright.

Using storage for memory swap space has been done for decades now - and your current [desktop] operating system is already doing it for you! The idea is that memory not accessed can be tucked away *on a much slower, but cheaper and more available storage* until it needs to be used. When it is used it is moved back to the *much faster* RAM.

See [Why not use SSD space as RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/617864/why-not-use-ssd-space-as-ram),  and elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

RAM is a volatile storage device that is it cannot hold files after the PC has shutdown. But hard disks are not volatile so they can store your files for ever, until you delete.

Comment: the question is not whether RAM can replace hard disk. It is whether hard disk can replace RAM.

Comment: The Hard disks are designed in such a way that it should be non volatile. So the storage and management of files in hard disk is different from RAM. This is one of the reasons why hard disks are slower. If you want to use hard disks as RAM then you need to reprogram your operating system to manage it. The non volatile property of HD is a constraint over RAM. So it is better to use HD as HD not as RAM.